# Effect of increasing number of network interface cards of a machine

Tags: networking, concurrency, interface

What is the effect of increasing number of NICs of a machine? Does this increase the number of requests processed per second?(In case of a server, does it allow to increase the number of concurrent client requests served by a server?)

Answer (score 0):

There are several layers in network infrastructure. Some are implemented in HW (and FW) and some in SW. Adding NICs is addition to HW/FW layers only. So indeed there is more bandwidth for the lower level traffic but for point-to-point connections the overall power is limited by the hosting machine. If it's powerful enough, increase in number of NICs can indeed increase the number of concurrent requests served (server is a good example).